# Properly creating a mouse event with Kivy

Tags: python, mouseevent, kivy, modeling

I am trying to create a program that will control the mouse on on my Kivy application. What is the proper way to create a provider and send it the locations I want to move and click at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the recorder module, it can both record events and also replay them

Here is a small example: (change RECORD to False to watch the replay after recording ... )

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.input.recorder import Recorder

rec = Recorder(filename='myrecorder.kvi',
    record_attrs=['is_touch', 'sx', 'sy', 'angle', 'pressure'],
    record_profile_mask=['pos', 'angle', 'pressure'])


def funky(b):
  print("Hello!!!")

  if RECORD:
    rec.record = False
  else:
    rec.play = False
  exit(0)

class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    if RECORD:
      rec.record = True
    else:
      rec.play = True
    return Button(text="hello", on_release=funky)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  RECORD = True # False for replay
  MyApp().run()
```

Now you can see the file myrecorder.kvi:

```
#RECORDER1.0
(1.1087048053741455, 'begin', 1, {'profile': ['pos'], 'sx': 0.65875, 'is_touch': True, 'sy': 0.51})
(1.1346497535705566, 'update', 1, {'profile': ['pos'], 'sx': 0.66, 'is_touch': True, 'sy': 0.51})
(1.1994667053222656, 'end', 1, {'profile': ['pos'], 'sx': 0.66, 'is_touch': True, 'sy': 0.51})
```

You can use the Recorder class in many other ways, see the docs:
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.recorder.html

You can wrap the recorder in a function to make a small helper:

```
#not tested
def click(x, y):
    with open("clicker.kvi", 'w') as f:
        f.write("""\#RECORDER1.0
(0.1087048053741455, 'begin', 1, {{'profile': ['pos'], 'sx': {x}, 'is_touch': True, 'sy': {y}}})
(0.1346497535705566, 'update', 1, {{'profile': ['pos'], 'sx': {x}, 'is_touch': True, 'sy': {y}}})
(0.1994667053222656, 'end', 1, {{'profile': ['pos'], 'sx': {x}, 'is_touch': True, 'sy': {y}}})""".format(x=x, y=y))
    rec = Recorder(filename='clicker.kvi',
                   record_attrs=['is_touch', 'sx', 'sy', 'angle', 'pressure'],
                   record_profile_mask=['pos', 'angle', 'pressure'])
    rec.play = True
    #should call rec.play = False somewhere?
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not looking to playback movements. I have a model that plays a game that's randomly generated but I need the model to be able to move the mouse and click. I can move a  "cursor" widget to the positions it should be at but I don't understand the documentation to actually send a motion event or touch to that location

Comment: @JacobKern look at its [source code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/input/recorder.py) it'll help you find what launches the click/touch event.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr - That won't be so easy, the recorder is an input provider so it generates its own events - not "firing" events to other providers. I have edited my anwser to include a small helper function that might help getting the desired result

Comment: @YoavGlazner You're right. Also, `rec.play=False` isn't necessary if you don't want to end it somewhere in the middle, which I think was mentioned in docs as causing ghost touches? To run something after it ends bind to `Recorder.on_stop` :)

Comment: @YoavGlazner Would it not be more proper to have an input provider dispatch a motion event?

Comment: @JacobKern - It would! *But*, I think it will be less generic since you have a few input providers and not all of them will be available on each OS/device.